# Jersey: Consuming application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded and testing it

Tags: java, jersey

I have been trying to figure out if it is possible to post json or form data to "same" method in jersey resource. Is the resource given below correct? If yes how can I test it. I have been trying hard to set Content-type and get context to the bean but it fails.

```
@Path("sample")
public class SampleResource {
  @POST
  @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, 
     MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
  public void post(Bean b) {
    // Get reference to the bean.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jersey will be able to convert JSON or XML to an instance of Bean only if @XmlRootElement annotation is attached to the Bean class (unless you wrote your own MessageBodyReader).
Jersey would not know how to convert form data to Bean, so for that you have to write your own MessageBodyReader.